# Retrieve entries that belong to the authenticated user

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core with Identity and Entity Framework Core.
How do I retrieve the pets that belong to the authenticated user?

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly PetContext _context;

    public HomeController(PetContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // User.Identity.IsAuthenticated -> true
        // User.Identity.Name --> bob@example.com

        ViewData.Model = _context.Pets.Where(pet => /* ...? */);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Is the `Pets` object supposed to contain a "PetOwner" property of type `string` that holds an email address that is compared to `User.Identity.Name`?

Or am I supposed to get a `IdentityUser` object from the `UserManager` and do something with that? Maybe the `Id` property? Should I have an `ApplicationUser` object that extends `IdentityUser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I have an ApplicationUser object that extends IdentityUser?

Yes! Your `ApplicationUser` and `Pet` classes should be as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public List<Pet> Pets {get; set;}
}

public class Pet
{
   public int PetId {get; set;}
   ........

   public string UserId {get; set;}
   public ApplicationUser User {get; set;}
}
```

Then update your Identity registration in `Startup.ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>() //<-- Replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` 
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppliclationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then your query should be as follows:

```
var loggedInUserId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
List<Pet> userPets =  _context.Pets.Where(pet => pet.UserId == loggedInUserId).ToList();
```

Comment: Why is `Pets` entity added to `ApplicationUser` and why is `ApplicationUser` added as a property to the `Pets` entity?

Comment: Its called one-to-many relationship between ApplicationUser and Pet.

Comment: @Fred Has my answer not helped you to overcome your problem?

Comment: Yes, it has! Is there any difference between `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` and _userManager.GetUserId(User); Which one is preferred?

Comment: I prefer first one but you can choose whatever you want!

Comment: Thanks for all your help! :)